# Web API two methods routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i running the  Web API  controller but only one method has pass in. how to pass in two methods ?

```
public List<activity2> GetAllCategories()
{

public List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
```

this my default route in my webapi config.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the parameter `sDir` to `id`, that will fix your problem.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public List<activity2> GetAllCategories(){//}

 [HttpGet]
 public List<String> DirSearch(string id){//}
```

Then keep the default route like:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**Update**

If you want to use `Attribute Routing` to achieve that, see below:

Install the AttributeRouting.WebApi nuget package:

```
 PM> Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi
```

Then add route attribute like:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/YourControllerName")]
 public List<activity2> GetAllCategories(){//}

 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/YourControllerName/{sDir}")]
 public List<String> DirSearch(string sDir){//}
```

For more details about Attribute Routing, see [Attribute Routing in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: i using mvc4, erm sorry but the route is underline red?

Comment: hi @GimYong, I updated my answer, this is the easiest way to solve your problem.